# How Can I Turn 120/80 into Two Columns (120 and 80)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column of blood pressures which read as ###/##, all I want to do is splint the numerator into one column and the denominator into another column.

Please help?

Comment: `tidyr::separate(df, first_bp, into = c("Systolic", "Diastolic"), sep = "/" , convert = T)` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df = data.frame(
first_bp = c("120/80","90/60"),
id = c("0001234","0001235"),
amount = c(18.50, -18.50), stringsAsFactors = F)
  
 
df %>%  
mutate(s0 = str_split(first_bp,"/")) %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(systole = as.numeric(s0[1]), 
       diastole = as.numeric(s0[2])) %>%
select(first_bp, id, amount, systole, diastole)
```

Comment: Thank you! <br/>

So the variable in my df is called first_bp, and when I do this \

mutate(s0 = str_split(first_bp,"/"), systole = as.numeric(s0[[1]]), diastole = as.numeric(s0[[2]])) %>% select(first_bp, systole, diastole)\

I get the error message "Error: Invalid index: out of bounds"\

I'll work on making a reprex, I know everyone says it's really easy to do but I swear it takes me forever..

Comment: I mean look, I can't even figure out how to create a new line. Why won't <p> work?!?

Comment: library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
tibble::tribble(
               ~first_bp,       ~id,  ~ammount,
  "120/80", "0001234",  "$18.50",
  "90/60", "0001235", "-$18.50"
  ) %>%
    mutate(s0 = str_split(first_bp,"/"), 
           systole  = as.numeric(s0[[1]]), 
           diastole = as.numeric(s0[[2]])) %>%
    select(first_bp, systole, diastole)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   first_bp systole diastole
#>   <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 120/80       120       90
#> 2 90/60         80       60

Comment: Please see if above works, edited with the data frame with your latest data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.split()` function.

Here is the example to do it:

```
blood_pressure = '120/80'
blood_pressure = blood_pressure.split('/')

numerator = blood_pressure[0]
denominator = blood_pressure[1]

print(numerator, denominator)
```

Output:

```
120 80
```